# UIView Background Image not showing

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, swift

I've defined a bg image in the Xcode Images.xcassets and want to use it as background for a view but the bg stays black. I'm using:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad();
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "background_ipad"));
}
```

this should work according to some other tickets on SO but for some reason the background stays black, not showing the image. Any ideas why this would happen?

Comment: you have image named "background_ipad" for your target? try NSLogging the value UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "background_ipad"));

Comment: The image is nil. The name is defined as "background_ipad" in the assets catalog. Does this not work with the assets catalog name (which automatically handles two image sizes)?

Comment: is the image avail for your project?

Comment: It should be, since it is in the assets catalog whose contents are automatically included when compiling, no? Otherwise, how can I found out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this code:

**SWIFT**

```
view.layer.contents = UIImage(named:"Image_Name").CGImage
```

**Objective-C**

```
view.layer.contents = (__bridge id _Nullable)([UIImage imageNamed:@"Image_Name"].CGImage);
```

Comment: One question though: Is it possible to prevent the image from stretching? I'm using the Launch Image and when it switches from launch screen to the actual ready state of the app there's a noticeable glitch where I see that the image stretches.

Comment: @Avalon : The view size and image size should be same. Else it will stretch if image size is less and view size is more. Its better to always have a exact size image.

Comment: I'm using the LaunchImage from the assets catalog which has an image version for every size and device orientation but it seems that when using this as view.layer.contents it will not update depending on the view size/orientation. Instead it seems to re-use just one of the images.

Comment: You will provide image name over there. So it will be one particular image which be used. It won't update. You will have to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the catalog image

[image]

and ensure target membership

[image]

Comment: Ok, thanks! That means my image should be available since the build target is checked. So this is not the problem. What else could be wrong?

Comment: instead of adding it to the catalog add image to the project itself.and ensure you are using proper name "background_ipad"

Answer (score 0):

For objective C

```
self.view.layer.contents = (__bridge id _Nullable)([UIImage imageNamed:@"Image_Name"].CGImage);
```

For Swift

```
self.view.layer.contents = UIImage(named:"Image_Name")!.CGImage
```